# Combine two data frames with one rows of one followed by one rows of another using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame like this:

```
df1
col1    col2
 A        1
 B        2
 C        3


df2
col1    col2
 E        4
 F        5
 G        6
```

I want to create one data frame by combining these data frames in such a way that one row of df1 followed by one row of df2.

The desired output is

```
df
col1    col2
 A        1
 E        4
 B        2
 F        5
 C        3
 G        6
```

I could do this using for loop and append the rows into a single data frame from both the data frames,

But I am looking for pandas shortcuts to do it most efficiently in pythonic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], 1, keys=(0,1)).stack(0).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    E     4
2    B     2
3    F     5
4    C     3
5    G     6
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    E     4
2    B     2
3    F     5
4    C     3
5    G     6
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `append` and `sort_index` will also work. You may add `reset_index` if you want `RangeIndex`

```
df1.append(df2).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

Out[536]:
  col1  col2
0  A    1
1  E    4
2  B    2
3  F    5
4  C    3
5  G    6
```

Comment: Adding `.reset_index(drop=True)` will probably make the answer perfect (index will also to continuous numbers)

Comment: @SH-SF: hehe... I agree. It is lazy part of me to not reset to `RangeIndex` :). Your comment motivated me to add it to the answer. I edited and added it :)